# Python Selenium Chrome loop through links in tabs

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Hi I have a main web page that opens in the main tab to accept cookies, and the rest of the links that should loop through open and close in tabs:

```
links = ['https://www.deviceinfo.me/','https://www.deviceinfo.me/','https://www.deviceinfo.me/','https://www.deviceinfo.me/','https://www.deviceinfo.me/']

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.deviceinfo.me/') #open the main tab

for link in links: 
    driver.execute_script("window.open();") # open a new tab
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])   # switch to the tab 1
    driver.get(link)
    driver.close() # close tab 1
```

But this doesn't work, any suggestions how to fix this?

thank you.

Comment: _But this doesn't work_: What doesn't work?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium thanks for reaching out, the below answer was what I needed, my issue was that the code above  would not open and close tab 1, which I use to loop through the links, along with the main tab that stays open all the time ( due to cookies pop up)

Comment: Good that you have got a working solution, however I'm totally against `driver.window_handles[n]`

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I have used quite a few of your answers on selenium here so far, if you don't mind writing your suggestion I would appreciate it.

Comment: okay :) I will put it on my ToDo list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

You basically got to the window_handle[1] but did not switch back to parent window and hence the issue

```
links = ['https://www.deviceinfo.me/','https://www.deviceinfo.me/','https://www.deviceinfo.me/','https://www.deviceinfo.me/','https://www.deviceinfo.me/']

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.deviceinfo.me/') #open the main tab

for link in links: 
    driver.execute_script("window.open();") # open a new tab
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])   # switch to the tab 1
    driver.get(link)
    driver.close() # close tab 1
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```